# Flot charts grid lines width

Tags: jquery, flot

I'm using [`flotchart.js`](http://www.flotcharts.org/) to generate graphs with grid lines.

I want to change the width of the inner grid lines.

This is my grid code:

```
grid: {
        gridLineColor: '#aabbcc',
        hoverable: true,
        borderWidth: 0,
        color: 'grey'
},
```

There is no option to increase the width.How can I change the width of the grid lines.
Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 2):

You have to edit the plugin to change this

if you go to line number `2040` you can find the below script

```
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
```

Change the `lineWidth` to what ever you want.

Hope this helps